# sed or awk : group by 2 columns and get the last value of another column

Tags: shell, awk, sed, group-by, aggregation

I need to quickly process a text file which has lots of redundancy.
I can use python, but I think the easiest and fastest will be using awk, sed or perl in the unix shell.

The data has 3 columns, I need to group by (unique) column 1 and 3, then get the last value of the 2nd column

```
1,2,3
a 1 A
a 2 A
a 3 A
b 2 C
b 3 C
b 3 D
c 1 C
c 1 D
c 2 D
```

The results should be like:

```
1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{key=$1 FS $3} !(key in arr){a[++n]=key} {arr[key]=$2}
END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i], arr[a[i]]}' file

1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

Comment: **Alternate solution using `tac`:** `tac file | awk '!seen[$1,$3]++{print $1, $3, $2}' | tac`

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks for the neat solution. Can you please me a brief explanation how awk "seen" is working here?

Comment: In the alternate solution, `seen` is an associative array with composite key as `$1,$3`. Expression `!seen[$1,$3]++` stores a value of `1` when composite key doesn't already exist in `seen` array. That way we are printing only first occurrence of given key and `$2` (since we have already reversed file using `tac`)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Input_file is same as shown sample and in sorted method of first and third field then following may help you in same.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print;
  next
}
!a[$1,$3]++{
  if(a[prev]){
    print prev,a[prev]};
  a[$1,$3]=$2
}
{
  prev=$1 FS $3
}
END{
  if(a[prev] && prev){
    print prev,a[prev]
}}
' SUBSEP=" "   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a special tool for this kind of tasks - `datamash`:

#### The partial solution, without the header:

```
datamash -W -t' ' --header-in -g 1,3 last 2 < input.txt
```

The header `1,2,3` was discarded for simplifying the demonstration code, because it has another field delimiter, than other rows, that complicates the task.

**Explanation**

- `-W, --whitespace` - use whitespace (one or more spaces and/or tabs) for field delimiters.
- `-t, --field-separator=X` - use X instead of TAB as field delimiter.
- `--header-in` - first input line is column headers (in our case, we are doing this just for omitting the header).
- `-g, --group=X[,Y,Z]` - group via fields `X,[Y,Z]`.
- `last` - the last value of the group.

**Output**

```
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

#### The full solution, which preserves the header:

```
cat <(head -n 1 input.txt) <(tail -n +2 input.txt | datamash -W -t' ' -g 1,3 last 2)
```

**Output**

```
1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tac` and GNU `sort`.

```
$ tac Group_Data | sort -u -k1,1 -k3 | awk '{if (NR == 1) print $0; else print $1,$3,$2}'
1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```

IMO python dictionaries and the powerful [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function makes python as fast and competitive as any other similar solution especially if you're going to use python to further process the data downstream. Below the items are grouped by using them as key to Python dictionary and then sorted by first and second element.

```
>>> groupdict = {}
>>> with open("Group_Data") as fp:
...     for ii, lines in enumerate(fp):
...         if ii == 0:
...             header = lines.rstrip()
...         else:
...             fields = lines.split()
...             groupdict[(fields[0],fields[2])] = fields[1]
... 
>>> groupdict
{('b', 'C'): '3', ('a', 'A'): '3', ('c', 'D'): '2', ('c', 'C'): '1', ('b', 'D'): '3'}
>>> for ii,elem in enumerate(sorted(groupdict.items(), key = lambda x : (x[0],x[1]))):
...     if ii == 0:
...         print header
...     key, value = elem
...     print key[0],key[1],value
... 
1,2,3
a A 3
b C 3
b D 3
c C 1
c D 2
```